# Tensor name "seq_embedding/map" not found in checkpoint files inception_v3.ckpt

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the show_and_tell model as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/im2txt#generating-captions) and the inception_v3 for inference using the `inference.py`, but I'm getting a **tensor not found** error. I do not know why this error occurs. The error stacktrace is as follows:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Building model.
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing vocabulary from file: /media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/word_counts.txt
INFO:tensorflow:Created vocabulary with 11508 words
INFO:tensorflow:Running caption generation on 1 files matching /media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/cliff_man.png
2017-05-25 18:36:49.509778: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-25 18:36:49.509813: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-25 18:36:49.509824: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-25 18:36:49.509843: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-25 18:36:49.509862: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-25 18:36:49.829698: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:405] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
2017-05-25 18:36:49.829786: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: gandalf
2017-05-25 18:36:49.829803: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: gandalf
2017-05-25 18:36:49.829854: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 381.9.0
2017-05-25 18:36:49.829916: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:369] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  381.09  Thu Mar 30 20:07:40 PDT 2017
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
"""
2017-05-25 18:36:49.829950: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 381.9.0
2017-05-25 18:36:49.829972: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:300] kernel version seems to match DSO: 381.9.0
INFO:tensorflow:Loading model from checkpoint: /media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/inception_v3.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/inception_v3.ckpt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 85, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 65, in main
    restore_fn(sess)
  File "/media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/inference_utils/inference_wrapper_base.py", line 96, in _restore_fn
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1457, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Tensor name "seq_embedding/map" not found in checkpoint files /media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/inception_v3.ckpt
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_382 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_382/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_382/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op u'save/RestoreV2_382', defined at:
  File "/media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 85, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/run_inference.py", line 51, in main
    FLAGS.checkpoint_path)
  File "/media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/bazel-bin/im2txt/run_inference.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/inference_utils/inference_wrapper_base.py", line 116, in build_graph_from_config
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1056, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1086, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 691, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 407, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 247, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 669, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Tensor name "seq_embedding/map" not found in checkpoint files /media/bhavya/New_Volume/ICT/UGRP/Implementation/im2txt/im2txt_copy/inception_v3.ckpt
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_382 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_382/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_382/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistakenly using the checkpoint of Inception V3 model to run inference for Show and Tell model.
Since, the weights of LSTM part of the network are not present in Inception V3 checkpoint file (see picture below), you have difficulties running it.
For you to run inference successfully, either [train the im2txt model from scratch](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/im2txt#initial-training) or [use a pretrained network like this](https://github.com/KranthiGV/Pretrained-Show-and-Tell-model#steps).
I hope it is clarified.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error generally occurs when your check-point file does not contain the tensor, you can comment on the repository it-self regarding the missing tensor. So I recommend you to check your check-point file for the missing tensor.